# Rails_admin remove the optional labels

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin

I am new in ruby on rails and I am using rails_admin gem for admin panel in my application. But it has so many labels for "Add New". However, there are some that I do not need.I already read the gem file which is https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki. But still confused that how can I remove them?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovhGW.png)

And also I do not know how to add current user id to this post, so that I do not need to select the user here.

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to answer both your questions with a code snippet please read the
comments

```
class YourObject < ApplicationRecord
  rails_admin do
    edit do
      field :user do
        help nil # This is the word 'Required' in your screenshot
        label 'Person' # for rails admin the label might mean something different than to you in this question

        default_value do
          bindings[:view]._current_user.id # This is what you want as the default
        end

        read_only true # You can go as far as not letting the current user to change this field
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the help keyword!

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove the "optional" key word using

```
help false
```